# Spotify SDK iOS: While Playing Music in background application will be crashed after few second

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, spotify, audio-player

I am playing Spotify music in background mode. It works fine. But after few seconds application will be crashed. I had tried to found solution but still i could not found any Proper Solution. Please help me.